# Insert custom button on Insert/Edit Link dialog?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I want to add a custom button on the Insert/Edit Link dialog/popup in tinymce v5.

I only got this code for the setup option where I put in call to a function.

```
function tinyMceEditLink(editor) {
    console.log("tinyMceEditLink");

    editor.on("click", function(e) {
        console.log("this click");
    });
}
```

Comment: Just fyi, for someone came across this. This doesn't work anymore on tinymce 6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll be the first to admit this is a bit hacky, but you could try:

```js
function tinyMceEditLink(editor) {
    editor.windowManager.oldOpen = editor.windowManager.open;  // save for later
    editor.windowManager.open = function (t, r) {    // replace with our own function
        var modal = this.oldOpen.apply(this, [t, r]);  // call original

        if (t.title === "Insert/Edit Link") {
            $('.tox-dialog__footer-end').append(
                '<button title="Custom button" type="button" data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-button" id="custom_button">Custom button</button>'
            );

            $('#custom_button').on('click', function () {
                //Replace this with your custom function
                console.log('Running custom function')
            });
        }

        return modal; // Template plugin is dependent on this return value
    };
}
```

This will give you the following result:

[image]

**Setup:**

```js
tinymce.init({
      selector: "#mytextarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
      plugins: "link",
      menubar: "insert",
      toolbar: "link",
      setup: function(editor) {
        // Register our custom button callback function
        editor.on('init',function(e) {
            tinyMceEditLink(editor);
        });

        // Register some other event callbacks...
        editor.on('click', function (e) {
            console.log('Editor was clicked');
        });

        editor.on('keyup', function (e) {
            console.log('Someone typed something');
        });

      }
    });
```

**Tips:**

1. You can replace `$('.tox-dialog__footer-end')...` with `$('.tox-dialog__footer-start')...` if you want your button on the left hand side of the footer.
2. This currently works on the default skin, changes to `.tox-dialog__footer` class could break this.
3. Any updates to the library that change the title "Insert/Edit Link" will break this.
4. The above example requires jQuery to work.
5. This is a bare minimum example. Use the configuration guide to customize the toolbar, setup events etc.

Comment: I got an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined on this line: editor.windowManager.oldOpen = editor.windowManager.open;

Comment: I added my setup above. How does it compare to yours?

Comment: Its alredy working now. I have other issues like editor event on keypress, keyup or keydown not working somehow.

Comment: I added to the setup code above to demonstrate how you would register other event callbacks like 'keyup' and 'click'. I just tested and it seems to work well.

Comment: hi @lance, I got this error on keyup "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Object.editor.windowManager.open [as oldOpen]" function callback with tinyMceEditLink(editor); in it.

Comment: any chance of an updated solution to this in tinymce 6.7.0?