# Insert custom button on Insert/Edit Link dialog box tinymce 6.7.0?

Tags: javascript, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-6

This: [Insert custom button on Insert/Edit Link dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55115042/insert-custom-button-on-insert-edit-link-dialog) is not working anymore with an error on this.oldOpen.apply the only available methods under editor.windowManager are:

```
alert()
close()
confirm()
open()
openUrl()
```

Able to add a custom element inside tinymce dialog box.

Comment: are you asking how to define a dialog box you control yourself and that you are opening using `editor.windowManager.open`? I ask to be sure.. because there are other options like "hacking" an existing dialog outside of your control (for example customizing the default table dialog in an unorthodox way)

Comment: @DiegoD I want to add a custom button on Insert/Edit Link dialog box beside URL button on this screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SRDQnxa_RK_nF65A0Cp_rCWA5xvFcFzW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I edited my answer explaining the 2 types of buttons you can use in a dialog (dialog buttons and footer buttons). You specifically need the dialog button. The dialog button I added is included in the root of the dialog `items`. If you need to position the button in a specific place you need to rely on dialog items that factor its layout (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dialog-components/#layout-components). The scope of the question didn't go as far as how to compose the layout of a dialog.

Comment: in the end I added a layout component to group the input field and the button next to it, in a single line

Comment: it took me forever to understand that you actually wished to modify an existing dialog instead of crafting your own.. I added on top the exact solution to achieve that particular goal -adding a button to the mceLink dialog. The onclick handler anyway is very generic and you won't easily have the objects returned by the editor events.. so there you will just rely on dom fetch and manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Changing an existing dialog opened by the link menu button

You can listen for the editor event `ExecCommand` and when its name is `mceLink` (being the command fired when opening the link dialog), you can fetch the dialog iframe using specific selectors and mutate its dom to add a custom button performing your own logic.

This is a full demo adding a `B` button next to the url text field:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/NhtB7PMWnW/2

```
tinymce.init({
  /*...*/
  setup: function (editor) {        
    /*...*/

    //when the event ExecCommand is fired on the editor
    editor.on('ExecCommand', function(e) {
      //if the command refers to the link dialog opening
      if (e.command === 'mceLink') {                
        //wait for the DOM to update before changing the dialog content
        setTimeout(function() {
          //retrieve the dialog content
          const iframe = document.querySelector('.tox-dialog__body-content');
          //dig down to the first input text field (being the URL)
          const urlTextField = iframe.querySelector('.tox-control-wrap .tox-textfield');                    

          //sets its width to 90% to make room for the extra button next to it
          urlTextField.style.width = '90%';

          //create a new button
          let customButton = document.createElement('button');
          customButton.textContent = 'B';
          customButton.classList.add('tox-button');
          customButton.style.marginLeft = '1px';
          customButton.onclick = function() {
            //this is the click event handler for the new button
            console.log('Custom button was clicked!');
          };
          
          //insert the new button next to the url text field
          urlTextField.parentNode.insertBefore(customButton, urlTextField.nextElementSibling);        
        }, 1);
      }
    });  
    /*...*/
  }
});
```

[image]

### Definining your own custom dialog having buttons

When definining a dialog you are going to open with `editor.windowManager.open(...)` you have the option to use to different types of buttons:

- [Custom dialog footer
  buttons](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dialog-footer-buttons/)
- [Custom dialog
  buttons](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dialog-components/#button)

Here I'm showing how to open a dialog having both kind of buttons:

```
function openMyCustomDialog(editor) {
    editor.windowManager.open({
        title: 'My Custom Dialog',
        body: {
            type: 'panel',
            //items composing the dialog
            items: [
                {
                    type: 'input',
                    name: 'myInput',
                    label: 'My Input'
                },
                //this is a dialog button
                //https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dialog-components/#button
                {
                  type: 'button',
                  text: 'CUSTOM DIALOG BUTTON',
                  buttonType: 'primary',
                  name: 'myCustomDialogButton',
                  enabled: true,
                  borderless: false
                }
            ]
        },
        //buttons composing the footer bar
        buttons: [
            //this is a footer button
            //https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dialog-footer-buttons/
            {
                type: 'custom',
                name: 'myCustomFooterButton',
                text: 'CUSTOM FOOTER BUTTON',                                
            },
            {
                type: 'cancel',
                text: 'Cancel',
                align: 'end'
            }
        ],

        //event triggering when action is taken on the dialog
        onAction: (dialogApi, details) => {
            //if the action target was myCustomFooterButton         
            if (details.name === 'myCustomFooterButton') {
                const msg = 'custom FOOTER button pressed!';
                console.log(msg);
                dialogApi.setData({ myInput: msg });
            }
            //if the action target was myCustomDialogButton         
            else if(details.name === 'myCustomDialogButton') {
                const msg = 'custom DIALOG button pressed!';
                console.log(msg);
                dialogApi.setData({ myInput: msg });
            }
        }
        
    });
}
```

The click on any of both buttons will fire a call to the `onAction` dialog event passing its `name` in the `details` argument.

This is a working example on **fiddle.tiny.cloud**

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/cPIkEAXqKj/11

The demo shared above also wraps in a layout bar the group containing the input field and the dialog button so that they will lay on a single line:

```
items: [
  //this is a row container (that will hold an input and a button next to it on the same line)
  //https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dialog-components/#bar
  //https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dialog-components/#layout-components
  {
    type: 'bar',
    items: [
      {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'myInput',
        label: '',
        maximized: true
      },
      //this is a dialog button
      //https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dialog-components/#button
      {
        type: 'button',
        text: 'CUSTOM DIALOG BUTTON',
        icon: 'bold',
        buttonType: 'primary',
        name: 'myCustomDialogButton',
        enabled: true,
        borderless: false,                    
      }
    ]
  }                
]
```

Here you can read more about layout components:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dialog-components/#layout-components
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dialog-components/#bar

You can find a live example covering buttons, from the official documentaion here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/dialog-examples/#interactive-example-using-redial