# Capture click events on selected if not all toolbar button

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-6

Toolbar buttons like: Insert/edit link, Insert/edit images, Insert/edit media, Insert templates and Source code

I already tried the

```
editor.on("ExecCommand", function(e) { // checking of e.command });
```

Only the first Insert/edit link works as I have a code that inserts a custom button right beside the URL button.

tinymce 6.7.0

Expected to insert a custom code on the click events on the tinymce toolbar buttons.

Comment: I was notified that someone upvoted my past answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77344990/insert-custom-button-on-insert-edit-link-dialog-box-tinymce-6-7-0/77345150#77345150) (I suppose it was because of you). By the way you just need to check the value of `e.command` inside the `ExecCommand` event handler you cited. Here are those values mapped to the corresponding toolbar button: `image` => `'mceFocus'`; `link` => `'mceLink'`; `media` => `'mceMedia'`; `template` => `'mceTemplate'`; `code` => `'mceCodeEditor'`;

Comment: If you have any doubt about which one is the command name, just console.log that value considering that the same event occurs for any toolbar button clicked

Comment: Yeah, it was me. Just visited the site for this problem but I already figure it out due to your answer on my previous question. Thanks though.

Comment: Additionally, I tried to do console.log on e.command but clicking on Insert/edit image doesn't display anything only after I close the dialog box that it spit out mceFocus